# SOAP Response with error without throwing exception

Tags: java, web-services, soap, log4j

I need to alter an existing web service written in JAVA.
The web service does some input validation and when for example the input for a number is invalid it throws an NumberFormatException.

This results in an error message for the user, this is correct.
But because we use log4j the exception is logged as an error in the log file, this is unwanted.

My question is:
How can I return a SoapFault without throwing an exception?
I think this will return an error to the user but doesn't log the error as error in the log file.
If this isn't possible. How can I configure log4j to not log certain exceptions?

Comment: which web service framework are you using?  can you share some code?

Comment: Try catching the NumberFormatException and re-throwing a SOAPFault. However we need to know what are you using (AXIS2 ?)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the number parsing in a try\catch block, catching the NumberFormatException. It won't propagate anywhere else, and in the catch block you can just return SoapFault.

```
int value;
try{
    value = Integer.parseInt(valueString);
}
catch(NumberFormatException e){
    value = 0;
    return SoapFault;
}
```

Comment: We're not using AXIS2. I think it is JWS. I see import javax.jws.WebService; I tried returning SOAPFault but that doesn't work because my method expects a string to be returned.

Comment: @PaulMeems I am no expert on J2EE, but maybe there is no other way - in order to get a SoapFault, you need to throw an exception of some sorts?

Comment: @PaulMeems OK if you need to return a String, what String corresponds to an underterminate value? Can you just return null?

Answer (score 0):

Returning null didn't solve my problem so I created a custom exceptions and excluded the class in my log4j.xml:

```
<category name="My.Company.DoNotLogException">
  <priority value="off" />
</category>
```

Now the user still gets an error, but the error doesn't shows up in my log anymore.

Thanks all for helping me.